# set states programmatically Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have two layouts both consisting of 2 TextViews each. The code goes like this

First Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_hours_spend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/total_hours_spend"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_selector"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_budget_spend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/total_budget_spend"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_selector"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Second Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_4dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_4dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/training"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
        android:text="Trainings"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Learning Programs"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_seventeen"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

For both these layouts, I have need to toggle between background images which I am doing using item_selectors.Something like this

Back_Selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner"/>

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_grey"/>
    </selector>
```

and Rectangle_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rectangle"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rectangle"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_rectangle"/>
</selector>
```

The default design for the screen is that TextView `Training` and TextView `Total hours spend` should be highlighted with the respective drawables set in the selector xml files.Also, one of the TextViews in both the layouts should be active all the time.

The problem is that only `Training` is highlighted when the app is launched. In the second layout, both the textViews are inactive.

When I click something on the second layout, the TextViews from the second layout becomes inactive.

What I mean is, out of 4 textviews two should be active all the time. 
But with the above code, I only have one TextVIew active.

What changes should I do here?

Comment: Can u post grey_rectangle,blue_rectangle,rounded_corner_grey, rounded_corner drawables also?

Comment: The drawables are mere images @Raghavendra

Comment: What do u mean by inactive? the text size for both the textviews are different, set android:textSize="17sp" for Total hours spend and see that is what u r expecting?

Comment: by active I mean, for the first layout the textview should have  background of  rounded_corner and for second layout the textview should have a background og rectangle_blue

Comment: I have used u r code looks to be fine I have used 2 different images textview highlighted in both the screens. Can u double check your image blue_rectangle and grey_rectangle once?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that each text view can have focus one at a time (drawable focused state), so if you click in another TextView, it will gain focus while the other loses it.

Bearing this in mind and also the fact that you need *one of the TextViews in both the layouts should be active all the time*, the best solution I can see to your problem is to have 2 `RadioGroups` containing 2 RadioButtons instead of the TextView's:

**First layout**:

```
<RadioGroup android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/total_hours_spend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="@string/total_hours_spend"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_selector"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/total_budget_spend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="@string/total_budget_spend"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_selector"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**Second Layout**:

```
<RadioGroup android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_4dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_4dp"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/training"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="Trainings"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="Learning Programs"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_seventeen"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**background_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rectangle"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_grey"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_grey"/>
</selector>
```

**rectangle_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rectangle"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/grey_rectangle"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_rectangle"/>
</selector>
```

This way it will work as you exposed.

If you still want to use TextView's, the only way I see is to create programmatically a TextView that implements the Checkable interface and then deal with the logic of having only one checked at a time in each layout. I think the solution I propose takes less time and achieves the desired effect.

Comment: I dont want a radio button, the design has to be TextView or a normal button

Comment: @Aayushi if you use a radio button it will still show as if it was a TextView since the android:button is set to **@null**. Do you have this in mind? Besides that, if you can use a button, a radio button is a button with different states. Please try the solution I gave you and see if you get what you want.

Comment: Okay, I didn'tt see android:button as null . Thanks,I thought that state_selected:true will work for TextView but that is also not working

Comment: With TextView the selected states won't work. Only if you created your own TextView that implements Checkable interface. See if the solution above works.

Comment: Did you put radio buttons inside RadioGroup? You have to be more specific about what you did, what you want and what you got when experimenting. I've been putting my time into answering this question and I think that it is polite to do so as a retribution for someone who is trying to help.